# How to find and use the nearest unused field name in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a users document and a user can add their own fields into this document. The fields are unnamed by default (because the user creates them by only clicking a button) but can be renamed by the user after creation through a separate operation.

If I wanted to find the nearest unnamed key under owned: (in this case it would be unnamed-4) and insert that that into the document how would I do that?

Or is there a better data model / method I should be using for this?

```
Users.update( id, {
    $set: {
        profile: {
            userfields: {
                owned: {
                  unnamed-1 : "field1",
                  unnamed-2 : "field1",
                  unnamed-3 : "field3",
                  mynamedfield : field 4
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use array instead of a map for owned, and use $push command when updating, in case you need to add another one.

```
Users.update( id, {
$set: {
    profile: {
        userfields: {
            owned: {
              unnamed: [
                "field1",
                "field1",
                "field3" ], 
              named: "field 4"
        }
    }
}
```

});

```
 db.Users.update(
                { id: id },
                { $push: { 'profiles.userfields.owned.unnamed': 'field4' } }
              )
```

Comment: You'd still need to scan the full array to find out that `field4` was available though, wouldn't you?

Comment: @WiredPrairie No, in this case there is just no need to scan anything, it would be `unnamed[4]` instead of `unnamed4`.

Comment: But when one of the indicies is removed, it would repeat? I was assuming the unnamed keys had values, as shown in the data.

Comment: I don't know, topic starter was not specific on that.

Comment: The unnamed keys would have values. A prefect analogy is creating a new folder in windows. The first created folder is "New Folder" the second would be "New Folder (2)" and so on. Now if you delete or rename "New Folder (2)" and then make another it would be named "New Folder (2)" and not "New Folder (3)" - the field values is analogous to what's in the folder, regardless of the name changing I want whats in the folder to stay the same.

Comment: So its perfectly valid that the solution would involve searching through all the keys to find the first opening for a unnamed-x key, inserting that key as well as the field value that goes with it.

Comment: Question if you do need that unnamed key or index in array is enough.

Comment: I don't understand?! or maybe I do. I think what you are asking is if the index works well enough for my purpose. In my case I would like to have the key be text like unnamed-1, unnamed-2, etc... because i want to make them human readable links (this is effectively an online folder system).

Comment: If you put a little bit more detail of what you are doing, we could be of little more help. Right now, my point is, you have an array named `unnamed` so for each element you have that name and index , combine them and you'll get `unnamed-1`.

Comment: I think your last comment made me understand your proposed approach and it could work. I'll write back more once I have it working.